# Duplicate Keys in Vue v-for Loop When Table is Sorted

Tags: sorting, vue.js, vuefire

My Vue application brings in data from Firestore using [vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/).

I import the data from a the 'lines' collection as follows:

```
firestore() {
  return {
    lines: db.collection("lines")
  }
}
```

Each record has a Firestore generated id, which I then use a a key in a v-for loop like:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th @click="sort_string(lines,'name')"> Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody v-for="line in lines" :key="line.id">
  <tr>
    <td>{{line.code}}</td>
    <td>{{line.name}}</td>
    <td>{{line.quantity}}</td>
    <button @click="pick_one(line)">+1</button>
    ...
```

In have a method `pick_one`which changes the quantity on Firestore directly:

```
pick_one(line) {

  const new_quantity = line.quantity + 1;      
  db
    .collection("lines")
    .doc(line.id)
    .update({ quantity: new_quantity });
}
```

All of this works fine ***until*** I `sort()` the underlying array ('**lines**').

If I sort the table and then call the function `pick_one` I get a duplicate key error:

```
[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: 'RaTIINFWTQxHQPyRmfsQ'. This may cause an update error.
```

I can only assume this has something to do with the way that Vuefire handles `update()` calls, since the act of sorting the array does not cause this problem, only updating a line in the array while it is sorted.

My sort function (vue method) looks like this:

```
sort_string(table, column) {
  console.log("sorting")
  this.sort_toggle = -this.sort_toggle;

  return table.sort((a, b) => {
    if (
      a[column].toString().toUpperCase() <
      b[column].toString().toUpperCase()
    ) {
      return -this.sort_toggle;
    }
    if (
      a[column].toString().toUpperCase() >
      b[column].toString().toUpperCase()
    ) {
      return this.sort_toggle;
    }
    return 0;
  });
},
```

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Can you show method that make sort? And check if Vuefire return same id after update

Comment: I have updated question to include sort function

Comment: How are you calling `sort_string`? Is that a method or a computed property? This may have something to do with [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) which mutates the original array

Comment: sorting per edited question above in the column header:
```<th @click="sort_string(lines,'name')"> Name</th>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phil's comment provided the clue to this behaviour - in that the `sort()` function is working on the underlying data rather than a copy.

I have modified my template so that the v-for now loops over a computed array which can be sorted using the (slightly modified) function.

The sort function now uses `slice()` to create a copy of the underlying array:

```
computed: {
  sorted_lines() {
    return sort_string(lines, this.sort_column) // name of the column/filed to sort by
  }
```

The sort_string function now looks like this (with addition of `slice()`

```
sort_string(table, column) {
  console.log("sorting")
  //this.sort_toggle = -this.sort_toggle; // moved elsewhere

  return table.slice().sort((a, b) => { // slice() then sort()
  if (
    a[column].toString().toUpperCase() <
    b[column].toString().toUpperCase()
  ) {
    return -this.sort_toggle;
  }
  if (
    a[column].toString().toUpperCase() >
    b[column].toString().toUpperCase()
  ) {
    return this.sort_toggle;
  }
  return 0;
});
},
```